# Slick Slider slidesToScroll

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I'm using slick slider to display 5 blocks of information. I've built it so on large screens the slider doesn't actually slide. Rather it just displays the blocks like floated divs. What I'd like to do on on mobile devices less than 768 picks is display some of the blocks and let the user swipe across to see all of it if they choose. Where I'm running trouble is that on mobile devices, I wrote slidesToScroll to be 1, where instead it seems to ignore the breakpoint I've written:

```
    $(".xb-reg").slick({
 dots: false,
 infinite: false,
 slidesToScroll: 2,
 variableWidth: true,
 autoplay: false,
 autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      responsive: [
           {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                     slidesToScroll: 1
                }
           }
      ]
});
```

Here's my html:

```
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="xb-reg slider">
    <div class="tkr">
      Info Block 1
    </div>
    <div class="tkr">
      Info Block 2
    </div>
    <div class="tkr">
      Info Block 3
    </div>
    <div class="tkr">
      Info Block 4
    </div>
    <div class="tkr">
      Info Block 5
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Just Remove Variable width True 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Pratice</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="slider-container">
        <div class="xb-reg slider">
            <div class="tkr">
                Info Block 1
            </div>
            <div class="tkr">
                Info Block 2
            </div>
            <div class="tkr">
                Info Block 3
            </div>
            <div class="tkr">
                Info Block 4
            </div>
            <div class="tkr">
                Info Block 5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".xb-reg").slick({
            dots: false,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            autoplay: false,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                }
            }]
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've looked at removing variable width, and that seems like the solution according to the documentation, but in my case it doesn't work for me. With the code you've written, my slider still scrolls 2 at a time on an iphone 7 and setting infinite to false the last slide is never shown. 

I had used variable width previously so I could control the width of the slides with css. At this point it's not an issue for me to continue to do that, but I'm wondering if there is an issue along those lines that's preventing this from working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Manish I was able to make some adjustments to the code and my css to arrive at the solution I needed.

```
$(".xb-reg").slick({
     dots: false,
     infinite: false,
     arrows: false,
     variableWidth: true,
     slidesToShow: 3,
     autoplay: false,
     autoplaySpeed: 2000,
          responsive: [
               {
               breakpoint: 9999,
               settings: "unslick"
               },
               {
                    breakpoint: 768,
                    settings: {
                         slidesToShow: 2,
                    }
               }
          ]
});
```